# How can I make WWW:Mechanize to not fetch pages twice?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I have a web scraping application, written in OO Perl. There's single [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) object used in the app. How can I make it to not fetch the same URL twice, i.e. make the second `get()` with the same URL no-op:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = 'http:://google.com';

$mech->get( $url ); # first time, fetch
$mech->get( $url ); # same url, do nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `WWW::Mechanize` and redefine the `get()` method to do what you want:

```
package MyMech;
use base 'WWW::Mechanize';

sub get {
    my $self = shift;
    my($url) = @_;

    if (defined $self->res && $self->res->request->uri ne $url) {
        return $self->SUPER::get(@_)
    }
    return $self->res;
}
```

Comment: if get() has not been called $self->res is undefined and this throws 'Can't call method "request" on an undefined value' on the first get.  Change the 4th line of sub get to 
if ( !$self->res || $self->res->request->uri ne $url) {
to allow get to be called.

Comment: This will ignore a second request *in succession* for the same URL. I assumed the OP wanted responses to be cached over any interval.

Answer (score 7):

See [WWW::Mechanize::Cached](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize::Cached):

> #### Synopsis

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Cached;

my $cacher = WWW::Mechanize::Cached->new;
$cacher->get( $url );
```

> #### Description
>
> Uses the [Cache::Cache](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Cache::Cache) hierarchy to implement a caching Mech. This lets one perform repeated requests without hammering a server impolitely.

Answer (score 4):

You can store the URLs and their content in a hash.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = 'http://google.com';
my %response;

$response{$url} = $mech->get($url) unless $response{$url};
```